# Should I add the unit 'px' to numerical values in the css function of jQuery?

Tags: jquery, integer

Is there any difference between the following?

`$(elem).css({ height : 100 })`

`$(elem).css({ height : 100+'px' })`

I've been searching for a long time in Google and I haven't found the answer. On jquery.com there are examples with px and just integer values... 
Is there some difference in browsers or OS ?

Comment: i dont think there is any difference

Comment: @dystroy Probably here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css.js#L221

Answer (score 8, accepted):

jQuery automatically adds the unit 'px' (as a default unit) to all numbers for the most css properties, including "height":

See line 221 in [src/css.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/85ee87b4444e1322f3a5b1a033902b3f9764b1ef/src/css.js#L221)

```
// If a number was passed in, add 'px' to the (except for certain CSS properties)
if ( type === "number" && !jQuery.cssNumber[ origName ] ) {
    value += "px";
}
```

`!jQuery.cssNumber[ origName ]` excludes the following css properties:

- columnCount
- fillOpacity
- fontWeight
- lineHeight
- opacity
- orphans
- widows
- zIndex
- zoom

(Side note: If you are like me at first a bit surprised about the exclusion of "lineHeight": [a number without a unit will be multiplied with the current font size to set the line height](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) - so there is a difference for the property 'line-height' when you specify / omit the unit)